# Grep with regex expression

Tags: regex, shell, grep, sh

I need the content between the fourth and fifth "|" on all lines starting with `FHEAD`. The goal is to apply the regular expression in grep to read files.

I have this expression that returns all content between "|"

```
(?<=\|)(.*?)(?=\|)
```

The goal in the example below would be to return

> 1047
>   8401-

```
FHEAD|1|PRMPC|20200217103050|1047|S
TMBPE|FHEAD|2|MOD
FHEAD|3|8401|230008|8401-|8401-Dcto|8401-Dcto 10FHEAD|1|235211|20190206000001|20190402235959|2||1||8||
TPGRP|4|240184
TGLIST|5|235213||||FHEAD
TLITM|6|101029605
TLITM|7|FHEAD101052978
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really have to use `grep`? `cut` or `awk` would be much easier.

Comment: What is expected output? Yes `awk` is better tool for this.

Comment: I have several files and I need to open and read the file to find the above content.

Comment: @RCLFA, As anubhava sir mentioned here, if you will post your expected output in your question in CODE TAGS we could better understand your question then, so kindly do edit your question with complete details and let us know then.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to creating doubts here. I think I fixed the issue in order to be clearer.

Comment: @RCLFA, but still it is not clear what are the conditions to get your shown sample expected output? So please clarify them in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @Barmar I can use cut or awk. I'm talking about grep because that's what I usually use.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 What's unclear? Get the 5th field of lines that begin with `FHEAD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the content of the fifth field (non-empty) on lines starting with `FHEAD`:

```
awk -F'|' '$1=="FHEAD" && $5!=""{print $5}' file
```

Comment: is it possible to add lines that only start with `FHEAD`?

Comment: @RCLFA What do you think `$1=="FHEAD"` does?

Answer (score -1):

```
awk -F '|' '$5=="1047" || $5=="8401-"{ print $0 }"  inputfile.txt
```

Above will find "1047" or "8401" in the fifth column of the inputfile "inputfile.txt"

```
grep -E "\|1047\||\|8401-\|" inputfile.txt
```

Above will do the same with grep (but this will not be restricted to column 5.

EDIT:
I must have missed the 'starting with `FHEAD`'....

```
awk -F\| '/^FHEAD/{ print $5 }'  inputfile.txt
```

or with grep

```
grep -e '^FHEAD|\(.[^|]*|\)\{3\}\(.[^|]*\)' -o inputfile.txt | grep  '.[^|]*|*' -o | grep -v '|$'
```

a combination of `grep` and `cut`:

```
grep -e '^FHEAD' inputfile.txt | cut -d'|' -f 5
```

Comment: works for this example. but if i apply other content in the same position, it no longer have results.

But thanks for the help

Comment: This doesn't look for lines beginning with `FHEAD` as specified in the question.

Comment: `1047` and `8401-` are just this example, they're not the specific values he's looking for always.